# Calculating common area between shapefiles using GDAL

Tags: gdal, shapefile, intersection, area, gdalwarp

I'm looking for a way to get the intersection area between my shapefiles.
Basically, I got three shapefiles from my *.tif* files like this:

```
gdaltindex a.shp a.tif
gdaltindex b.shp b.tif
gdaltindex c.shp c.tif
```

This way I got the area of my .tif files.
Now I would like to get a new shapefile via intersection.
I thought about using `gdalwarp`, for example like this:

```
gdalwarp -cutline intersection.shp a.tif a_intersection.tif
gdalwarp -cutline intersection.shp b.tif b_intersection.tif
gdalwarp -cutline intersection.shp c.tif c_intersection.tif
```

but i can't figure out how to get the intersection.shp file I can do it via QGIS, but would like to do it directly from GDAL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with GDAL, but you can create the intersection shapefile with [mapshaper](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper)'s `-mosaic`.

With the following, you

- read in all shapefiles
- mosaic them together, so all overlaps are converted into their own feature
- calculate the number of overlaps for each feature
- sort the features, and get the one with the most overlaps

```
mapshaper -i *.shp combine-files -merge-layers -mosaic calc='OVERLAPS=count()' -sort 'OVERLAPS' descending -filter 'this.id==0' -o intersection.shp
```

To simplify things, you could use

```
gdaltindex footprints.shp *.tif
mapshaper footprints.shp -mosaic calc='OVERLAPS=count()' -sort 'OVERLAPS' descending -filter 'this.id==0' -o intersection.shp
```